# Why is my SQLDataReader just reading the last row from database table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sqldatareader

The same query works fine in SQL Server. I need it to return all rows read from the DB table in c#.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT TypeName, Sum(HitNo) FROM TypeHit GROUP BY TypeName";

SqlDataReader sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
sdr.Read();

if (sdr.HasRows)
{
   while (sdr.Read())
   {
       TextBox1.Text = sdr.GetString(0) +" at " + sdr.GetInt32(1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `sdr.Read()`, that will advance the reader to the next block of data?

[DataReader.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You're also overwriting the `TextBox`'-Text property for every record in the reader since `while (sdr.Read())` is a loop.

```
using(SqlDataReader sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                TextBox1.Text += sdr.GetString(0) + " at " + sdr.GetInt32(1) + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "No rows found.";
        }
}
```

[Retrieving Data Using a DataReader (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to append result in loop:

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text+sdr.GetString(0) +" at " + sdr.GetInt32(1);
```

Also, from performance point of view, it's better to use `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
if (sdr.HasRows)    
{    
   while (sdr.Read())    
   {    
      bld.Append(sdr.GetString(0));
      bld.Append(" at ");
      bld.Append(sdr.GetInt32(1));    
    }    
 }
 TextBox1.Text = bld.ToString();
```

Comment: I have tried that it do not work, even when I count the number of rows the sdr returns it is just one

Answer (score 0):

In each loop you replace the last TextBox1.Text with the data fetched.
So you end up with only the last line. If you need to see all the results you need something like this.

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   while (sdr.Read()) 
   { 
       sp.AppendLine(sdr.GetString(0) +" at " + sdr.GetInt32(1)); 
   } 
   TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

also change the TextBox **MultiLine** property to **True** and *resize* the TextBox1 to show more than one line

ouch ... missed the bogus sdr.Read() before loop....